# How do I "enrich" every record in a Pandas dataframe with an hour column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some dataframe in Pandas:

```
 1   2
 a  .2
 a  .3
 b  .5
```

I would like to add, for each of those records, a column with hour (from 0 to 23), so it will look like

```
 1   2    3
 a  .2    0
 a  .2    1
 a  .2    2
...
 a  .2   23
 a  .3    0
 a  .3    1
...
 a  .3   23
 b  .5    0
...
 b  .5   23
```

Comment: What's stopping you?

Comment: Also, are there 24 values of `a`, 24 of `b`?  Or if there were more than that, would you want to keep counting up, or re-start at 0?

Comment: @TomKimber: knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the *hours* array:

```
import numpy as np
hours = np.tile(np.arange(24), len(df))
```

Repeat each record of `df` by 24 times:

```
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(24)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Assign the *hours* array as a new column to the data frame:

```
df[3] = hours

df.head()
#   1     2 3
#0  a   0.2 0
#1  a   0.2 1
#2  a   0.2 2
#3  a   0.2 3
#4  a   0.2 4
```

---

Put together:

```
def expand_hours(df):
    import numpy as np
    hours = np.tile(np.arange(24), len(df))
    df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(24)].reset_index(drop=True)
    df[3] = hours
    return df
```

Answer (score 0):

If your DataFrame is called `df` try this:

```
df['hour'] = Series(np.random.randint(0,24), index=df.index)
```

This should add a column with name 'hour' filled with integers generated between 0 and 23.